# Issue passing variable to Ansible playbook for hosts: with double quotes

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write a playbook that kicks off role playbooks and pass a list of hosts to it. The "master" playbook has some load balancing logic in it that I don't want to repeat in every role playbook and can't put into site.yml.

inventory.yml

---

```
[webservers]
Web1
Web2
Web3
Web4
```

master.yml

```
---
- name: Split Inventory into Odd/Even
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Set Group Odd
      set_fact:
        group_type: "odd"
      when: (inventory_hostname.split(".")[0])[-1] | int is odd

    - name: Set Group Even
      set_fact:
        group_type: "even"
      when: (inventory_hostname.split(".")[0])[-1] | int is even 

    - name: Make new groups "odd" or "even"
      group_by:
        key: "{{ group_type }}"

- name: Perform Roles on Odd 

  include: webservers.yml hosts={{ groups['odd'] | join(' ')}}


- name: Perform Roles on Even 

  include: webservers.yml hosts={{ groups['even'] | join(' ')}}
```

webservers.yml

---

```
- name: Perform Tasks on Webservers
  hosts: webservers:&"{{ hosts | replace('\"','')}}"
  roles:
    - pause
```

The join(' ') flattens the list of hosts into a string with a space separating each one. When I run the playbook it passes the list of hosts to webservers.yml, however it adds double quotes to the beginning and end, causing webservers.yml to do nothing since no hosts match. I would assume the replace('\"','') would remove the quotes around the string but doesn't seem to be the case. Here's an example output from webservers.yml:

`[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: Web4"`

`[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: "Web2`

Any ideas? Does `hosts:` handle filtering differently?

Comment: I don't see any reason for the `replace('\"','')`. Works perfectly fine without. Where do you get `"` from? What does your inventory look like?

Comment: I do not understand.  What is the "load balancing logic" for?

Comment: @techraf the inventory simply looks like [webservers] Web1 Web2 Web3 Web4 , without the replace the extra var "hosts" passed to webservers.yml is printed like "Web2 Web4", so when it attempts to parse that string for hosts it evaluates as "Web2 and Web4", as you see in the warnings. I attempted the replace to remove the quotes around "Web2 Web4" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jack The load balancing logic is remove all odd boxes from load balancer, run ansible tasks on odd, put them back into load balancer, repeat for even. I omitted the actual LB tasks from above playbooks to make the problem easier to identify.

Comment: You produce an unquoted string and quote removal is not required. The code you posted in the question works properly (although `replace('\"','')` is unnecessary).　The only thing with this code: you get a warning for using reserved keyword for variable name `hosts`.　Or you are using some obsolete Ansible version with some bug.

Comment: @techraf your comment got me to take a second look and the quotes were being inserted from my use of the variable insert hosts: webservers:&"{{ hosts | replace('\"','')}}", switching it to this hosts: webservers:&{{ hosts }} produces my wanted results.. but now I have a new problem to figure out. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @batzos These groups do not seem to be dynamic.  An odd server will always be an odd server, and an even one will always be even.  If this is true, you can just define those groups in your inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you use a role and a play in a wrong way. When you do tasks you should not change list of hosts this task or role is been executed upon. Basically, only play (a thing with 'hosts: ..., tasks: ..., roles: ...') can control where to run.

There are few exceptions, f.e. you can play with delegation and so on. But for your case any attempt to use tasks or roles to control list of the host will only bring misery and hate (toward yourself, toward ansible, etc).

To do it right, just add yet another play in to your playbook (playbook is a list of plays).

Here is your code, slightly modified.

```
---
- name: Split Inventory into Odd/Even
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Set Group Odd
      set_fact:
        group_type: "odd"
      when: (inventory_hostname.split(".")[0])[-1] | int is odd

    - name: Set Group Even
      set_fact:
        group_type: "even"
      when: (inventory_hostname.split(".")[0])[-1] | int is even 

    - name: Make new groups "odd" or "even"
      group_by:
        key: "{{ group_type }}"


- name: Doing odd things
  hosts: odd
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: Perform Roles
     include: webservers.yml


- name: Doing even things
  hosts: even
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: Perform Roles
     include: webservers.yml
```

You can see, I've just assigned a playbook to two groups ('odd' and 'even'). Dynamic groups are preserved between plays in a playbook, and they are no different from any other group in this matter.

P.S. Do not use 'include', use 'import_tasks' (includes are dangerous in newer versions of ansible, avoid them if you could.).